# Running ROS + Gazebo on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that in principle it should work. Run linux on the Pi, connect a screen, keyboard and mouse, install ROS and Gazebo and it should work.

But I have not tried it myself. Specifically running ros and Gazebo at the same time to make the Raspi a viable albeit low power development platform for ROS.

Have you tried it, and if so could you share what you used?

- model Raspi
- OS installed
- ROS version

What was your experience?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342846/running-ros-+-gazebo-on-raspberry-pi/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2020-01-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zmk5](https://answers.ros.org/users/44691/zmk5/) on 2020-01-29**:
I'm pretty sure you can run it because they do have binaries within Ubuntu repositories for arm. I'm not sure how the performance will be though. Maybe a raspberry pi 4 would be a good option instead of a RPI3.

**Comment by [Celebrimbor](https://answers.ros.org/users/74585/celebrimbor/) on 2021-06-22**:
I have tried runing ROS Noetic on RPi3 B+ with Ubuntu mate 20.04 and things did't go well at all, i suffered from huge laggs and most of the times my RPi gets stuck and freezes due to the huge load. I also tried runing ROS Melodic on the same Pi, and the same thing happened.

My advice to you is that you use RPi 4 with at least 4Gb of RAM, because i've seen a lot a people on the intrernet using it with ROS Noetic, Gazebo and rviz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It works. I have done it. I am running Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04 Server on a Raspberry Pi 3+. It took many tries but I finally got it working. Run as few nodes as possible on the Pi and offload most of it to a connected computer.

---

Originally posted by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) with karma: 628 on 2021-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2021-06-24**:
That's awesome, have you tried ROS2 by any chance?

**Comment by [SANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/103803/sana/) on 2022-04-30**:
Hi
can you help me to do that i have a raspberry pi 4 and i install Ubuntu 20.04 on it . i install desktop for Ubuntu. i can install ROS1-Noetic  but i can not install gazebo. can you explain what did you do step by step. thanks a lot